# Ruby on Rails - appending params to end of URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I want to add the param/string `utm_campaign` to the end of my url if it exists. I was thinking about a helper method that checks the url and if the `utm_campaig`n is there it automatically puts it to the right.

- `test.com/home/?utm_source=test`
- `test.com/home/?utm_source=test&utm_campaign=testit`

I also need to permit it on every link change action.

For example:

I am on `test.com/home/?utm_source&utm_campaign=testit` and have a contact form that, once done, sends me to `test.com/contact` - without permitting the params.

How would I achieve this?

I have something like this right now:

```
def url_include_campaign?
    url = request.path_info
    if url.include?('utm_campaign')

    end
  end
```

Comment: I think this is a case when the best way to solve a problem is not to solve it )  Why do you need the parameter to be at the end?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - for checking if the `utm_campaign`, you can use `request.query_parameters`.

To add the param to the URL, I would do it like this:

```
def url_with_campaign
  if request.query_parameters.fetch('utm_campaign', false)
    # utm_campaign is set, do whatever you need
  else
    new_query_params = request.query_parameters
    new_query_params['utm_campaign'] = '##SOMETHING##'
    redirect_to "#{request.base_url}#{request.path}?#{new_query_params.to_query}"
  end
end
```